# Facebook Login / Register without HTTPS?

Tags: facebook

Can I implement Facebook Login / Register without moving my whole site to HTTPS? Maybe just having Mysite.com/login under https and the rest on http?

I don't really need all the functionality from Facebook during the user session,  it's only a way to make login / register faster for users

Comment: You dont need do "move" to https. You just need to setup openssl. People can access your site trough "http" and "https". No need to move

Comment: By move I mean having just one version, in this case HTTPS, for SEO purposes

Comment: It is possible, but makes not much sense IMHO. If you have a valid SSL certificate for your domain already, then you should rather move it all over to HTTPS. (Unless you need to embed external resources that are available via HTTP only or something like that.) HTTPS is faster than HTTP: http://www.httpvshttps.com/

Comment: Of course, but then i will lose my SEO traffic, at least for a few days or weeks. That's what I want to avoid.